# How to display a numeric answer instead of a calculation?

Tags: matlab, equation

I keep getting answers as a calculation instead of numeric answer, like the following:

```
(291*pi*((30*3^(1/2))/13 - 1)*((13*3^(1/2)*((30*3^(1/2))/13 - 2))/400 + 197/200))/13
```

I would rather like to have a numerical answer, i am no MATLAB expert can someone please help me?
Following is the code that leads to this. (All variables except m has been defined earlier)

```
syms m ;

eqn=(d+m* d* ((sqrt(3))/2)<f); 

M = solve(eqn,m);     
disp (M)


r= (b/2)+d*((M-1)*sqrt(3)+2)/(4);

L=2* pi* M* w* (r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying the result:

```
syms m ;

eqn=(d+m* d* ((sqrt(3))/2)<f); 

M = solve(eqn,m);     
disp (M)


r= (b/2)+d*((M-1)*sqrt(3)+2)/(4);

L=simplify(2* pi* M* w* (r))
```

**EDIT**

Since L is a numeric value, the answer is:

```
L = vpa(2* pi* M* w* (r))
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. Error message:

Undefined function 'simplify' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Does vpa function work? https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/472395-why-does-matlab-substitute-a-number-in-a-formula-instead-of-solving-it

Comment: Realised that i had changed the code so simplify worked, but not as well as i hoped. The resulting answer is now shorter, but still a calculation.
:(291*pi*(7429*3^(1/2) - 4316))/33800

Comment: I think you are looking for vpa(L). If L is always a numeric answer you can use double, but take into account that it will give you an error if L is a symbolic answer.

Comment: The vpa function seems to work. Thank you! @PedroRodriguez

Comment: Please, mark the answer as accepted if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
eval(L)
```

to convert the anser from symbolic to double ( if there isn't a symbolic variable left in the expression).